# The problem of skipping without being called

Tags: c++

[image]

I'm currently using the ISO C++14 standard version of VS 2022.

During the Debug build, I found a strange phenomenon that the code written on line 23 is not being called.

It can be solved by simply adding dummy code, but what is the cause of this phenomenon?

Comment: Post code as text not as image.

Comment: Also, try `std::cout << i << std::endl;` instead of `printf`.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the project?

Comment: @cwbusacker Yes, it's the same even if you rebuild

Comment: Looks like your debugger needs to be debugged :)

Comment: Are you building in debug or release mode? It looks like the line is optimized away, since the `i` variable is unused, unless you add the `printf`.